# How can I avoid getting this MySQL error Incorrect column specifier for column COLUMN NAME?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment, ddl

How can I avoid getting this MySQL error **Incorrect column specifier for column topic_id** ?

MySQL Error...

```
#1063 - Incorrect column specifier for column 'topic_id'
```

SQL Schema...

```
CREATE TABLE discussion_topics (
    topic_id char(36) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    project_id char(36) NOT NULL,
    topic_subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    topic_content TEXT default NULL,
    date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    date_last_post DATETIME NOT NULL,
    created_by_user_id char(36) NOT NULL,
    last_post_user_id char(36) NOT NULL,
    posts_count char(36) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (topic_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To use `AUTO_INCREMENT` you need to deifne column as `INT` or floating-point types, not `CHAR`.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` use only unsigned value, so it's good to use `UNSIGNED` as well;

```
CREATE TABLE discussion_topics (

     topic_id INT NOT NULL unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
     project_id char(36) NOT NULL,
     topic_subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     topic_content TEXT default NULL,
     date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
     date_last_post DATETIME NOT NULL,
     created_by_user_id char(36) NOT NULL,
     last_post_user_id char(36) NOT NULL,
     posts_count char(36) default NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (topic_id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Maybe i'm being lazy but is there an easy 1-2 sentence way to define the difference in dummy terms as to `UNSIGNED` vs `SIGNED` I have no idea what that means unfortunately and I don't have time to read for an hour right now?

Comment: Well, when you define classic INT, it is signed, values from -2147483648 to 2147483647, but autoincemented values can be only plus signed, so when you use unsigned, mysql expects numbers from 0  to 4294967295, son in same, INT is 4kb and in that same 4kb, you can use two times more entries :) hope you understand

Comment: "signed" means "can be negative". The "sign" is simply the minus symbol in front of the number.

Answer (score 7):

The `auto_increment` property only works for numeric columns (integer and floating point), not `char` columns:

```
CREATE TABLE discussion_topics (
    topic_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    project_id char(36) NOT NULL,
    topic_subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    topic_content TEXT default NULL,
    date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    date_last_post DATETIME NOT NULL,
    created_by_user_id char(36) NOT NULL,
    last_post_user_id char(36) NOT NULL,
    posts_count char(36) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (topic_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the [**doc**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html):

> Some attributes do not apply to all data types. `AUTO_INCREMENT` applies
>   only to integer and floating-point types. `DEFAULT` does not apply to
>   the `BLOB` or `TEXT` types.

In your case, you're trying to apply `AUTO_INCREMENT` modifier to `char` column. To solve this, either drop `AUTO_INCREMENT` altogether (that means you'll have to generate a unique id on the application level) or just change `topic_id` type to the relevant integer one.

As a sidenote, it makes little sense using `char(36)` to store the posts *count*, so that column's type probably has to be changed as well. It looks like you're going this way to prevent integer overflow - but if you're dealing with more than `18446744073709551615` posts (the biggest number that can be stored in `BIGINT UNSIGNED` column) in a single topic, you have far bigger problem on your side probably. )

Comment: I knew it!  Well I thought that might be the problem but skimming over the Docs I missed this, thanks for pointing it out in the Docs too

Answer (score 4):

You cannot auto increment the `char` values. It should be `int` or `long`(integers or floating points).
Try with this,

```
CREATE TABLE discussion_topics (
    topic_id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    project_id char(36) NOT NULL,
    topic_subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    topic_content TEXT default NULL,
    date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    date_last_post DATETIME NOT NULL,
    created_by_user_id char(36) NOT NULL,
    last_post_user_id char(36) NOT NULL,
    posts_count char(36) default NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That was a mistake. Thank you M.Svrcek

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, but using Long type. I changed for INT and it worked for me.

```
CREATE TABLE lists (
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 desc varchar(30),
 owner varchar(20),
 visibility boolean,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
```